# Integrating my php web application with sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I've created a php platform that allows users to upload videos and that shows them in categories and so on. It's written in php with a mysql database.

Now i'd like to integrate the system with sharepoint 2010. The main objective is to show the list of videos the way it's shown on my current site, the secondary is to allow the user to add a video from sharepoint to my system, so it can be seen in the sharepoint list too. Third objective, which would be nice to have, is to be able to search the video (on title) from the sharepoint search functionality.

I'm new to sharepoint, but i'm fluent in asp.net and php, so programming would be no issue. I've tried to hack it by trying to show my current site in sharepoint using an iframe on a new page, but sharepoint removes the iframe tag upon save, because it's insecure.

Should i be looking in creating a new Content Type? Or is that an invalid path for my quest?

Comment: I can use a webpart to create an iframe, but it's still the lesser of the options.. I hope.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the answer I posted? If it helps solve your problem, you can upvote it by clicking on the ^ arrow and flag it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check mark icon next to my answer.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, because creating a silverlight app is also time intensive and that decision has been postponed. Thanks for your suggestion though! It is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint 2010 includes support for Silverlight applications. Since you're already fluent in .NET, perhaps you could create a Silverlight app to display your videos.

Some links to get you started:

[Silverlight and SharePoint 2010: Better together](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/matthijs/Silverlight-and-SharePoint-2010-Better-together)
[Getting Started With Silverlight and SharePoint 2010](http://bryantlikes.com/GettingStartedWithSilverlightAndSharePoint2010.aspx)
[Silverlight and Sharepoint 2010: Getting Started](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-and-Sharepoint-2010-getting-started.aspx)
[SharePoint 2010 Silverlight Client Object Model - How to use](http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-silverlight-client.html)